# django + angular , displaying django error message in angular

Tags: javascript, python, django, angular, typescript

I am creating an app for practice using Django(drf) and angular 8, i want to show error message sent by Django in case of any fail in validation.

Problem is, i am not able to get the response body which contains error message in angular with {observe: event} while doing HTTP post with {observe: 'events'}, using {observe: 'events'} for progress bar.

angular code

```
postData(
    fileToUpload: File,
    empName: string,
    dept: string
  ): Observable<any> {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    formData.append("emp_name", empName);
    formData.append("dept", dept);
    return this.http
      .post(
        "http://localhost:8000/post/add",
        formData,
        { reportProgress: true, observe: "events" }
      )
      .pipe(tap((result) => {}, catchError(this.handleError<any>("postData"))));
  }
```

above is call in below code

```
public onSubmit(FileUploadFormData: NgForm) {
    let post: any = [];
    post = this.post;

    this.isFileUploading = true;
    const fileList: FileList = FileUploadFormData.value;
    this.empName = FileUploadFormData.value.empName;
    this.dept = FileUploadFormData.value.dept;

    this.uploadService.postData(this.file, this.empName, this.dept).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        switch (response.type) {
          case HttpEventType.Sent:
            console.log("inside sent");
            break;
          case HttpEventType.ResponseHeader:
            console.log("inside header");
            break;
          case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
            this.percentage = Math.round(
              (response.loaded / response.total) * 100
            );
            console.log(`Uploaded! ${this.percentage}%`);

            break;
          case HttpEventType.Response:
            console.log("inside response", response.body);
            this.zone.run(() => {
              this.post = [];
              this.post = post;
              this.post.unshift(response.body);
            });
            this.percentage = 0;
        }
        if (this.percentage == 100) {
          this.percentage = 0;
          this.isFileUploading = false;
          console.log(response.body);

          this.toastr.success("Successfully posted");
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
        this.loading = false;
        this.isFileUploading = false;
        this.toastr.error("failed posting");
      }
    );
    FileUploadFormData.reset();
  }
```

while debugging, when i look for error in console, i get below

[image]

now if i enter "sales" as employee department in form than error message from django comes like

```
if not emp_dept.startswith("Dept"):

    return Response({"error": {'errorMessage': "Department name should start with 'Dept-' "}}, status=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)

reponse of django is

{"error":{"errorMessage":"Department name should start with 'Dept-' "}}
```

now what i get is "failed posting", how will i show this error message coming from Django in angular? I don't get error.body, or response.body so that i can use the error message sent by Django.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the browser, press on F12 and make a call to the API then go to the Network tab and check the content of the response of Django API call then add it here

Comment: @MFuatNUROĞLU {"error":{"errorMessage":"Department name should start with 'Dept-' "}}

Answer (score 0):

Change error handling function from

```
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
    this.loading = false;
    this.isFileUploading = false;
    this.toastr.error("failed posting");
  }
```

To :

```
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
    this.loading = false;
    this.isFileUploading = false;
    this.toastr.error(error.error.errorMessage);
  }
```

Comment: error doesn't have error.error.errorMessage, i have updated the description, and have put in the image of error